# creating a list of imageviews and displaying in the linear layout in activity android

Tags: android, imageview

I am making an app in which i am getting an array of images from server. I need to display these images in my activity through dynamic array of imageviews and then ad these in linearlayout. i have used the folloeing code but getting null pointer exception.

```
         URL myFileUrl =null;  
            myFileUrl= new URL(imageUrl);
            int imageIndex = 0;
            int n=stringOnTextView.length;
            System.out.println(n);
             for (int row = 0; row < Math.ceil(n/3); row++) 
            {
                for (int column = 0; column < 3; column++) 
                {
                     myFileUrl= new URL(imageUrl);

                    HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection)myFileUrl.openConnection();
                    conn.setDoInput(true);
                    conn.connect();

                    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                    bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                    System.out.println(images[imageIndex]);
                    images = new ImageView[n];

                    images[imageIndex].setImageBitmap(bmImg);

                    System.out.println("cccccc");
                    layoutImages.addView(images[imageIndex++],(column * 80)+20,(row * 80)+20);
```

Comment: are you getting URL for the images?

Comment: Why you want to create dynamic imageview inside the LinearLayout? instead you can display the same images inside the ListView (Custom listview with images)

Comment: the prooblem is not with the layoutr I get null pointer exception in array of imageview I am editing my question . CAn u then tell me

Comment: Do you just have List of imageviews, is it the case?

Comment: yes i am getting an array of images from where i had to download images and display them in my app

Comment: array of images means array of URLS string of images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are not initializing arrat images[] that's why you r getting null pointer exception.

```
images = new ImageView[n]
```

change your code as shown above.